# Upload capture video to server using FormData in ionic 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, html5-video, ionic4

I have successfully captured the video recording from my android device but unable to upload it to the server using formData and unable to show the video in html. below is my code:

video.ts

```
captureVideo() {
let options: CaptureVideoOptions = {
  limit: 1,
  // duration: 30,
};
this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(
  (res: MediaFile[]) => {
    let capturedFile = res[0];
    this.readVideoFile(capturedFile);
  },
  (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
);
}

readVideoFile(file: any) {
//console.log('inside readVideo', file);

var movVideo = {
  uri: file['localURL'].split('/'),
  type: 'video/mp4',
  name: file.name,
  size: file.size,
};
var imageBlob = new Blob([file], movVideo);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', imageBlob, file.name);
//console.log('FORM DATA 515 ---->', formData.getAll('data'));
this.upload.captureFileUpload(formData).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    // Store the token value in local storage for future use.
    //console.log('------------captureImageFileUpload resp--------', res);
  },
  (err) => {
    //console.log('------------captureImageFileUpload err--------', err);
  }
);
}
```

video.html

```
<ion-icon
    name="videocam"
    class="send"
    slot="end"
    (click)="captureVideo()"
    *ngIf="!isDesktop"
  ></ion-icon>


  <video controls class="chat-video">
   <source src="{{attachment_file_path}}?name={{attachValue.fileName}}" type="{{attachValue.mimeType}}"/>
    Your browser does not support HTML video.
  </video>
```

Any help much appreciate